Did Congress ever ban Peter Thiel's IRA maneuver?
Back in 2021 there was a big kerfuffle when it became known that Peter Thiel had put a bunch of his PayPal stock in a Roth IRA, essentially avoiding needing to pay capital gains tax on about $5 billion (see here for example).
There were various proposals to prevent this in the future, for example by requiring withdrawals when accounts reached $10m (which the typical person would be quite unlikely to hit, even if they never diversified into bonds).
I was following this with some interest, but at a certain point the story seemed to have gone dead. I've tried researching it and can only find articles from right when it happened. I'm curious, did Congress ever pass anything to actually prevent this?

https://www.propublica.org/article/why-you-cant-turn-your-roth-ira-into-a-billion-dollar-tax-shelter has a good analysis of what actually happened, written after the immediate uproar had died down.

The maneuver istelf (funding the self-directed IRA and then using it for private shares acquisition) is hard to outlaw. The only point of contention may be self-dealing, which the propublica article also mentions but I don't know if it is relevant to Thiel specifically. The proposals are to limit the size of Roth accounts, but they're unlikely to ever materialize.

I think you meant to ask whether Congress ever tried to ban giant IRA accounts. Peter Thiel didn't really do any special "maneuver". He just put $1,700 of PayPal stocks to his IRA account in 1999, (and frankly this was bad financial decision), and the stock luckily went rocket high. This can happen to any super-lucky stockpickers. Banning this maneuver means forbid stock picking in an IRA account.

@xuhdev he was one of PayPal founders though. The stock wasn't publicly traded then, so it's more than "super lucky stock picker"

@littleadv I don't think it matters for the purpose of understanding the OP's real question. Whether it's about public or private shares, it's ultimately stock picking in nature.

@xuhdev true, and there are ira custodials who allow ways to do angel investing

None of these proposals have become laws. Generally, the tax shielding and avoidance schemes for super-rich are unlikely to change given the way elections work in the US.

Sounds pretty opinion-based.

@RonJohn what exactly?

The second sentence.  I agree with it, but it's still a political opinion.

Yes, it's my estimate of probabilities, that's what "Generally" and "unlikely" mean.
